# can you make a sort of column in txt file java

Tags: java

I have a text file that contains lines like the following:

```
00001:dexter:1989:9
```

In other words, each line contains fields where the field delimiter is the colon character (`:`). Is there any way to access each field and get, for example, `dexter` as a string? I've tried using method `useDelimeter()` and then reading the first line but it's not a string. This is the program:

```
Scanner sc;
String token=null;
sc = new Scanner("00001:dexter:1989:9");
sc.useDelimiter(":");
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    token = sc.next();
    System.out.println(token);
}
System.out.println(ss.substring(0, ss.indexOf(":")));
```

Is there a way to read any field as a string anytime?
I'm new to java and new to SO so any answer will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest using a CSV library. Most of which allow to change the delimiter. Otherwise, `split(":")`

Comment: The snippet you shared prints our each "column" individually. Can you elaborate what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I don't recommend using split because it uses regexp and proper escaping is required. This can cause bugs if you are not careful.

Comment: @Mureinik as in i wonna get a specific one as a string for example and use it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method I can think of is :

```
String getColumn(int n,string s)
{
   return ( n <= 0 ) ? s.subString(0,s.indexOf(":")) : getColumn(--n,s.subString(s.indexOf(":") + 1 , s.length);
}

getColumn(1,"00001:dexter:1989:9"); // Returns dexter
```

This function recursively splits the string until the required column is the column it starts with. Then it splits that column and returns it.

---

Input a:b:c , n = 1

- Step 1 -> b:c
- Step 2 -> b

That is in short it removes columns from the front until n > 0 and then removes all columns from the back leaving only the required column.

Comment: so if i wanted to lets say write to a file called dexter.txt and wanted to get dexter from txt file what could i do?

Comment: And what about `"00001:dexter:1989:9".split(":")[n]` if you already know the desired column index being `1` in this case?

Comment: `return ( n <= 0 ) ? s.subString(0,s.indexOf(":")) : getColumn(--n,s.subString(s.indexOf(":") + 1 , s.length)` – Well, this may or may not work. But if I were to review your code, it would not pass. This is not code golf.

Comment: @MC Emperor so what can we replace this code with instead?